# Eclipse custom plugin-deployed as a jar not working

Tags: eclipse, plugins, deployment, jar

I have no errors while running my plugin project in the runtime workbench but when I try to deploy it as a jar (using Export Wizards link), the jar file created does not work in other standard eclipse versions. I have tried putting the jars in the plugins folder of various eclipse installations, but to no avail. Can anyone please tell me what the issue might be all about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a single plugin with no feature, you can add your deployed plugin jar to the `eclipse/dropins/` folder. See [the dropins folder](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/misc/p2_dropins_format.html) for more information.

Comment: Hey thanks!! I reinstalled eclipse and it works fine now. Anyway, how do we display a console for my system.outs in the jar? Is there any way I can do that, or any other debugger I could use?

Answer (score 0):

I found some information here:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/Where_Is_My_Bundle

What I have done so far:

- open an osgi console (there is a symbol on the console window which
  allows you to add an osgi console - with pde installed)
- use the command 'ss' in the console to list all bundles (i had to change my name to a name without dots for the plugin to be listed)
- manually start the plugin with its id to show occurring exceptions

(from what I read just now, a plugin can also silently fail, the .log file didn't show any errors either)